# anchor tag within an echo command

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, logout

I am developing a simple website and want to display login and logout buttons depending on whether the user session is set or not. The code is as shown in this image[image: Code]

on running it I get this error **You don't have permission to access /mysite/< on this server.**

Comment: there is something wrong with your server settings

Comment: it could be more (and probably is), but you have too many apostrophes in checking userdata (3rd line).

Comment: Note: Please include the snippets of code as text, formatted as [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), rather than images. The `{}` button in the post editor can help with this.

Comment: @hummingBird i think thats working fine. the problem should be somewhere between the echo command. both login and logout are displayed but problem arises when i click the buttons

Comment: Please post text, not image. It was already asked half an hour ago. Also, your code has three errors: one missing parenthesis and two unbalanced quotes. Please make sure your code parses correctly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your session is look like this

```
$session = array(
    'id' => $result[0]['id'], // Some user id. Ex: 007
    'username'  => $name, // User name. Ex: James Bond
    'logged_in' => TRUE
);
```

---

So you set the session using `$this->session->set_userdata($session);`. Ok all set. And now you load the respective view.
On there you can do two things.

1. **This view loads after validate correct user**. If user is **incorrect you redirect to `login` page**. Else you load this page. So **just can show the logout button only**.
2. If **using session use the common** variable like **`logged_in`** which assign to session.

   ```
   <?php
   if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE) 
   {
       // Logout Button code
   } 
   else 
   {
       # Redirect to logging page
       redirect('');
   }
   ```

> As well check the BaseURL and htaccess too